# Replace axis line which has been set as a style before

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles

I can't figure out how to override the axis line style from "with arrow" (set in a style) to "without arrow".

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
axisStyle/.style={axis y line =left, 
          axis x line =bottom,
          axis line style ={very thick}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbc]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   axisStyle, 
            axis y line=none,
            axis y line*=left, 
            axis x line*=bottom,
            ymax=5
        ]
            \addplot[domain=-2:2] {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see neither does it work to simply set the line style to "without arrow" nor does it help to first set it to none.

Note: In reality my style contains of course much more options, therefore it would be still reasonable to use the style and just change those two settings if possible.

Comment: Use `axis line style={-}` in the axis options to override the `axisStyle` and locally set no arrow tip for the axis line.

Comment: @PaulGessler That works. If you formulate an answer I will accept. Maybe you could also explain, why my version does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the styling of the axis lines, use `<axis> axis line style={<styles>}`, where `<axis>` is the axis to modify (`x`, `y`, `z`, or omit to style all axes) and `<styles>` is the styling to apply.

So, we can use `axis line style={-}` in the `axis` options to override the `axisStyle` and locally set no arrow tip for the axis line. Here I've omitted the `<axis>` since only one axis line is drawn, but the effect is the same with `x axis line style`.

Those keys will be *appended* to the currently installed axis line style, which is why `axis line style ={very thick}` from `axisStyle` is still in effect.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfplotsset{
  axisStyle/.style={
    axis y line =left,
    axis x line =bottom,
    axis line style ={very thick},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axisStyle, 
  axis line style={-},
  axis y line=none,
  ymax=5,
]
  \addplot[domain=-2:2] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd be happy to explain why your version doesn't work, but you haven't shown code for your attempt to modify the style of the axis lines.

Comment: I meant the MWE I posted, I tried it with the `axis y line*=left` option.

Comment: @MrZ that key won't do anything to the x-axis line; it applies to the y-axis, which you've told `pgfplots` not to draw. In any case, that key (and variants for the other axes) has to do with positioning of the axis lines, not styling.

Comment: Maybe I should explain a bit more what I mean: When no axis option is set, and I use `axis x line*=left`, I get a line left without an arrow. Now, if I set `axis x line=left` I get it with the arrow. However, overriding now with `axis x line*= left` does not do anything. So I thought, maybe first set the axis line to `none` and then use the `*` option, this was my second attempt which I tried with the y-axis.

Comment: @MrZ I think it has to do with the order that styles are installed, but I'd have to dive into the code to know for sure. I'm reading about it in Section 4.9.9 of the v1.12 manual. In any case, using my method will append to anything previously installed, guaranteeing the correct result.